# Should entity have methods and if so how to prevent them from being called outside aggregate

Tags: domain-driven-design

So, if there is an entity within an aggregate what is the best/usual way to prevent outside world from doing something like `Aggregate.Entity.SomeMethod()`? (in case there is a getter for an entity on aggregate)

Should aggregate expose entity at all or should its getter always give a value object representation of entity? (actually a copy to break a direct reference)

Or, on the other hand, should entity be anemic and all its methods moved to aggregate?

Comment: would downvoter be kind to explain downvote so i can improve the question? thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aggregates should not expose data in a way that permits the aggregate's internal state to be changed from the outside.

That means that the aggregate root object should not be handing out references to internal entities.  If you want to change the state of the aggregate, you send a message to the root entity, and that logic decides whether to do the work itself or delegate it.

Queries of the root object should return values.

There's not much point to anemic entities -- if you are going down that road, you might as well keep things simple with value objects.

> thanks for you answer! could you just please extend an answer with: 1) does that mean that aggregate should expose copy of the entity to the outside world so that its internal entity is immutable from outside? or how does it expose it? 2) wat do you mean by 'queries of the root object should return values'?

Short answer: you shouldn't be exposing "entities" outside of the aggregate at all.

The motivation for entities is that they change state.  The motivation for aggregates is that they coordinate changes of state among entities.  If you leak an entity out of the aggregate, then the aggregate no longer has the ability to coordinate all of the changes.

Therefore: if you want to change an aggregate, "tell, don't ask".  You pass information to the aggregate root, and it will in turn create/modify the appropriate entities within the root.

If you don't want to change an aggregate, then use a query that returns an immutable representation of the answer to the query.   The precise nature of that immutable representation may vary from language to language; in the original Domain Driven Design text, the examples were taken from Java, where immutable representations are implemented using "value objects".  See chapter five of the [blue book](http://a.co/38oyzqg).

Comment: thanks for you answer! could you just please extend an answer with: 1) does that mean that aggregate should expose copy of the entity to the outside world so that its internal entity is immutable from outside? or how does it expose it? 2) wat do you mean by 'queries of the root object should return values'?

Comment: oh oh oh, so entity is just in aggregates internal tool to keep its state and not meant to be exposed to outer world. i must say that's an eye-opener! and then i guess, whatever aggregate does expose to outer world does not affect its invariants which are always enforced through explicit aggregate methods. right? (yes/no is enough)

Comment: what confuses me is that at least repository will need data from all aggregates children, including entities. so at least for that purpose, in order for repository to be able to map aggregate to DAO, entity attributes (relevant to saving to db) should be exposed but i guess then, as value objects.

Comment: i am probably  reading too much atm but i just don't understand purpose of entity within aggregate root. it doesn't have identity outside of the aggregate, it shouldn't be exposed, never accessed directly....what's the purpose of its identity then? ok, maybe it would make sense in collections within aggregate but other than that, i don't see any use.

Comment: An entity (being an aggreate root or being a child entity in the aggregate) exists per se, not because it has to have any purpose. An entity within an aggregate DO have an identity outside the aggregate!, all entities have. And you could access entity by its id if the root entity does it, what you cannot do is access the entity directly, but you can through the root. Usually an entity inside an aggreagate is like a weak entity in the E/R model, or a composition in UML. The id use to be compose (part of it is the id of the root).

Comment: "i just don't understand purpose of entity within aggregate root" -- @deezg, that's a really good question, and should probably be asked separately from here.  TL;DR because we are modeling a domain....

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52069929/what-is-the-purpose-of-child-entity-in-aggregate-root please feel free to leave your thoughts there. I would really appreciate it as i feel this is one important piece of a ddd puzzle that i'm missing. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is a question of visibility scope. It would depend on the programming language you are using. In java for example, I put an aggregate in a package. The aggregate root entity will be public. The others will have package scope, ie, no keyword for visibility.

Comment: so your aggregate root would be in a dedicated package?

Comment: Not just the root. The whole aggregate is a package. The package contains all the aggregate elements: the root entity, the other entities, the value objects, ... The only element with the "public" access modifier should be the root entity. The rest of the elements should have no access modifier, so that they won't be accesible from outside the package, they have just package visibility.

Comment: yes yes, you're right, sorry. i meant, you would have dedicated package per aggregate? sounds like alot of packages for any decent sized project (although, i don't know much about java and best practices with packages).

Comment: Not too much packages, as a bounded context doesnt have many aggregates usually. First you have a package for each BC, then a package for each aggregate inside each BC. Even more... each BC is an independent package, it's a deployable unit, a microservice. Otherwise you would have a monolith, which isnt that bad anyway as you have your code well organized in packages. And yes, best practices in packages is to use public keyword just on the things you want to expose outside the package, the other things should be hidden using no access modifier for them

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! thats a lot of useful infos!

Comment: You are wellcome. It's ok if it has helped you or anyone who read it.