# What is the purpose of child entity in Aggregate root?

Tags: domain-driven-design

[ Follow up from this question & comments: [Should entity have methods and if so how to prevent them from being called outside aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51907447/should-entity-have-methods-and-if-so-how-to-prevent-them-from-being-called-outsi/51907574?noredirect=1#comment91079114_51907574) ]

As the title says: i am not clear about what is the actual/precise purpose of entity as a child in aggregate?

According to what i've read on many places, these are the properties of entity that is a child of aggregate:

1. It has identity local to aggregate
2. It cannot be accessed directly but through aggregate root only
3. It should have methods
4. It should not be exposed from aggregate

In my mind, that translates to several problems:

1. Entity should be private to aggregate
2. We need a read only copy Value-Object to expose information from an entity (at least for a repository to be able to read it in order to save to db, for example)
3. Methods that we have on entity are duplicated on Aggregate (or, vice versa, methods we have to have on Aggregate that handle entity are duplicated on entity)

So, why do we have an entity at all instead of Value Objects only? It seams much more convenient to have only value objects, all methods on aggregate and expose value objects (which we already do copying entity infos).

PS.
I would like to focus to child entity on aggregate, not collections of entities.

---

[UPDATE in response to **Constantin Galbenu** answer & comments]

So, effectively, you would have something like this?

```
public class Aggregate {
    ...
    private _someNestedEntity;

    public SomeNestedEntityImmutableState EntityState {
       get {
          return this._someNestedEntity.getState();
       }
    }

    public ChangeSomethingOnNestedEntity(params) {
       this._someNestedEntity.someCommandMethod(params);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Entity should be private to aggregate

Yes. And I do not think it is a problem. Continue reading to understand why.

> 2. We need a read only copy Value-Object to expose information from an entity (at least for a repository to be able to read it in order to
>    save to db, for example)

No. Make your aggregates return the data that needs to be persisted and/or need to be raised in a event on every method of the aggregate.

Raw example. Real world would need more finegrained response and maybe `performMove` function need to use the output of `game.performMove` to build propper structures for `persistence` and eventPublisher:

```
  public void performMove(String gameId, String playerId, Move move) {
    Game game = this.gameRepository.load(gameId); //Game is the AR
    List<event> events = game.performMove(playerId, move); //Do something
    persistence.apply(events) //events contains ID's of entities so the persistence is able to apply the event and save changes usign the ID's and changed data wich comes in the event too.
    this.eventPublisher.publish(events); //notify that something happens to the rest of the system
  }
```

Do the same with inner entities. Let the entity return the data that changed because its method call, including its ID, capture this data in the AR and build propper output for persistence and eventPublisher. This way you do not need even to expose public readonly property with entity ID to the AR and the AR neither about its internal data to the application service. This is the way to get rid of Getter/Setters bag objects.

> 3. Methods that we have on entity are duplicated on Aggregate (or, vice versa, methods we have to have on Aggregate that handle entity
>    are duplicated on entity)

Sometimes the business rules, to check and apply, belongs exclusively to one entity and its internal state and AR just act as gateway. It is Ok but if you find this patter too much then it is a sign about wrong AR design. Maybe the inner entity should be the AR instead a inner entity, maybe you need to split the AR into serveral AR's (inand one the them is the old ner entity), etc... Do not be affraid about having classes that just have one or two methods.

In response of dee zg comments:

> What does persistance.apply(events) precisely do? does it save whole
> aggregate or entities only?

Neither. Aggregates and entities are domain concepts, not persistence concepts; you can have document store, column store, relational, etc that does not need to match 1 to 1 your domain concepts. You do not read Aggregates and entities from persitence; you build aggregates and entities in memory with data readed from persistence. The aggregate itself does not need to be persisted, this is just a possible implementation detail. Remember that the aggregate is just a construct to organize business rules, it's not a meant to be a representation of state.

Your events have context (user intents) and the data that have been changed (along with the ID's needed to identify things in persistence) so it is incredible easy to write an `apply` function in the persistence layer that knows,  i.e. what sql instruction in case of relational DB, what to execute in order to apply the event and persist the changes.

> Could you please provide example when&why its better (or even
> inevitable?) to use child entity instead of separate AR referenced by
> its Id as value object?

Why do you design and model a class with state and behaviour?

To abstract, encapsulate, reuse, etc. Basic [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) design. If the entity has everything needed to ensure domain rules and invariants for a operation then the entity is the AR for that operation. If you need extra domain rules checkings that can not be done by the entity (i.e. the entity does not have enough inner state to accomplish the check or does not naturaly fit into the entity and what represents) then you have to redesign; some times could be to model an aggregate that does the extra domain rules checkings and delegate the other domain rules checking to the inner entity, some times could be change the entity to include the new things. It is too domain context dependant so I can not say that there is a fixed redesign strategy.

Keep in mind that you do not model aggregates and entities in your code. You model just classes with behaviour to check domain rules and the state needed to do that checkings and response whith the changes. These classes can act as aggregates or entities for different operations. These terms are used just to help to comunicate and understand the role of the class on each operation context. Of course, you can be in the situation that the operation does not fit into a entity and you could model an aggregate with a V.O. persistence ID and it is OK (sadly, in DDD, without knowing domain context almost everything is OK by default).

Do you wanna some more enlightment from someone that explains things much better than me? (not being native english speaker is a handicap for theese complex issues) Take a look here:

https://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2016/07/14/DDD-Aggregate-Decoded-1
http://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2016/07/14/DDD-Aggregate-Decoded-2
http://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2016/07/14/DDD-Aggregate-Decoded-3

Comment: Thanks for your input! I have 2 questions: 1. what does `persistance.apply(events)` precisely do? does it save whole aggregate or entities only? 2. Can you show some real world example where it is clearly better to model things with child entity and not with value object on aggregate? (please, for single child entity, not a collection of them). thanks!

Comment: i am reading your answer again and you nailed another one of my dilemmas: i just cannot spot that middle ground between value object on AR and separate AR. i fail to see real world need for child entity. could you please provide example when&why its better (or even inevitable?) to use child entity instead of separate AR referenced by its Id as value object?

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking about data. Stop that. :) Entities and value objects are not data. They are objects that you can use to model your problem domain. Entities and Value Objects are just a classification of things that naturally arise if you just model a problem.

> Entity should be private to aggregate

Yes. Furthermore all state in an object should be private and inaccessible from the outside.

> We need a read only copy Value-Object to expose information from an entity (at least for a repository to be able to read it in order to save to db, for example)

No. We don't expose information that is already available. If the information is already available, that means somebody is already responsible for it. So contact that object to do things for you, you don't need the data! This is essentially what the [Law of Demeter](https://javadevguy.wordpress.com/2017/05/14/the-genius-of-the-law-of-demeter/) tells us.

"Repositories" as often implemented *do* need access to the data, you're right. They are a bad pattern. They are often coupled with ORM, which is even worse in this context, because you lose all control over your data.

> Methods that we have on entity are duplicated on Aggregate (or, vice versa, methods we have to have on Aggregate that handle entity are duplicated on entity)

The trick is, you don't have to. Every object (class) you create is there for a reason. As described previously to create an additional abstraction, model a part of the domain. If you do that, an "aggregate" object, that exist on a higher level of abstraction will never want to offer the same methods as objects below. That would mean that there is no abstraction whatsoever.

This use-case only arises when creating data-oriented objects that do little else than holding data. Obviously you would wonder how you could do anything with these if you can't get the data out. It is however a good indicator that your design is not yet complete.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! first of all, sure enough my model is nowhere near complete:). btw, i dont use any orm. /questions about your input: 1. what is an alternative to repositories for save? 2. if entity is private to aggregate and we still need entity state outside of aggregate (in event, in some domain service, whatever the case may be) how else would we expose it than duplicating it on aggregate as value object? 3. i very well might be thinking in terms of data and i am willing to stop. how should i think?:) 4. could you show real word example of child entity implementation?

Comment: actually, let me broaden last question from comment: could you please show real world example of child entity that cannot/should not be implemented using value object and why is it so? i think that would help me alot

Comment: "*We don't expose information that is already available.*" - i guess this is a complete unknown for me: if entity is private to aggregate and we need entity state outside of aggregate what options do we have except for duplicating entity's state on aggregate level to expose it?

Comment: Could I ask How to make an entity private to aggregate, and this rule should be considered to the client code also, or just we talking about other aggregates ?

Comment: @deezg Alternative to Repository: First, try to blend it into the Domain. I saw `AccountEntry` and `AccountEntryRepository` at a bank, which could have been: `Transaction` and `Ledger` respectively. `Ledger` is a natural repository. If there is nothing you can find, you may have to "hide" it below business methods. E.g. `Account.transfer(...)` internally does persistence without a "Repository".

Comment: @deezg Value Object vs Entity in Aggregate: It does not matter which type of object is "aggregated". The point is not to expose it, not even in read-only form. Here is how to think about it: Instead of thinking "I need the data, because I have to do something with it later in some service or whatever", think about those things _now_, and put all of those things here into the object. If you do that you obviously won't need the data anymore.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam that feels interesting. if i read you correctly you are almost saying expose nothing but behavior/methods? and, if that is the case, doesnt that mean explosion of aggregate in size? and i have read that breaking down aggregates into smaller ones is considered a better practice. also, what does that mean to domain services that need to update one aggregate based on data from other? are you saying that thats a sign of bad design also? (too small aggregate)

Comment: @deezg Yes, expose only behavior. Almost all of the important OO principles say this very thing. Encapsulation, Law of Demeter, Tell don't Ask, etc. That doesn't mean that all of the behavior has to be in the aggregate directly. The aggregate should delegate behavior to less abstract objects (whether value objects or entities is not important), until the behavior is small enough to be in an object directly. Furthermore the aggregate should expose business-related functions only. Those then can be called by anybody, services and other aggregates alike.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam ok, now i understand you and it sure does make sense. and now its clear why you say repositories are bad pattern. but then i guess i have no idea how to solve persistance as repository as usualy implemented is all i have seen as ddd persistance related so far. i am aware it exceeds the scope of this question but would you be so kind to show example or explain how to do persistance if AR doesnt expose any data? thanks a lot!

Comment: @deezg There's a lot of ways. The easiest is just to let the objects persist themselves or whatever they need. When I call business method `Account.transferFunds()`, the method does the persisting for me, because it represents the full business transaction. Or, if you're doing event sourcing, you can ask the object to deliver you events when it changes, or to forward them directly to some event store. You can ask the object to present itself in some JSON or XML format, in case that is part of the requirements, etc.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam so in first scenario your model is persistance aware? isnt that a big no-no in ddd?

Comment: @deezg It only becomes bad (i.e. unmaintainable) if you mix it. The `Account` might be a pure database-based implementation, in that case it's ok. If it's not, it might use a collaborator (or many) who is. Or it might be a decorator, i.e. layered objects with different aspects of the same function. However, this topic might be too big for a comment section.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam you are right, we can't exhaust this topic in comments form. Let me just say, events (that something that does persistance listen to) definitely do make sense but aren't they yet another form of sharing data from AR to outside world? / Decorator is another story; if i understand you correctly, decorator would depend on persistance implementation and do the save to db, right? if so, that one makes most sense to me so far (not that my judgement is relevant:) ).btw, do you feel its worth turning this into a separate question or is it too broad to cover in stackoverflow form?

Comment: and thank you so much because you definitely shed some new light on this topic for me!

Comment: *You can ask the object to present itself in some JSON or XML format, in case that is part of the requirements, etc* - just to add a comment: isn't this just another way of having AR persistence aware which might be especially hard to maintain if we use noSQL with fluid schema?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. It has identity local to aggregate

In a logical sense, probably, but concretely implementing this with the persistence means we have is often unnecessarily complex.

> 2. We need a read only copy Value-Object to expose information from an
>      entity (at least for a repository to be able to read it in order to
>      save to db, for example)

Not necessarily, you could have read-only entities for instance.

The repository part of the problem was already addressed in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916107/how-should-aggregate-expose-info-from-child-entity/51930035#51930035). Reads aren't an issue, and there are multiple techniques to prevent write access from the outside world but still allow the persistence layer to populate an entity directly or indirectly.

> So, why do we have an entity at all instead of Value Objects only?

You might be somewhat hastily putting concerns in the same basket which really are slightly different

- Encapsulation of operations
- Aggregate level invariant enforcement
- Read access
- Write access
- Entity or VO data integrity

Just because Value Objects are best made immutable and don't enforce aggregate-level invariants (they do enforce their own data integrity though) doesn't mean Entities can't have a fine-tuned combination of some of the same characteristics.

Comment: i know you have addressed some of these issues on other  question and please take my appologies if i'm circling around a bit touching same points a few times but i want to have full&complete understanding. Could you please explain a bit how could you have `read-only entities`? What would happen with their behavior/methods? or are you talking about VO representation of entity's data fields?

Comment: https://www.jefclaes.be/2013/04/designing-entities-immutability-first.html

Comment: thanks for the link! I've read it but if we put his end result class (`Customer`) on some aggregate as exposed, readonly entity, its methods would be accessible from the outside of AR. or am i missing something?

Comment: Yes, they will by default. `Internal` (or `protected`in Java) can be helpful here.

Comment: so that means having one AR per package/assembly, right?

Comment: I wouldn't go to such an extreme. There's only so much you can do with defensive programming before it starts hurting you more than it serves.

Comment: that's so true! and that's exactly what this endeavour with me trying to grasp strict/by-the-book ddd is all about. of course i could do all in less-than-strict mode but i am trying to see how much could be done very strictly and that it still makes sense practically.

Comment: IMHO, there's no such thing as real by-the-book DDD. There are principles (original ones and later variations thereof), and there are the constraints of your platform/language/tools/context/legacy code...

Comment: well, sure, i can understand that. but there are some very strong statements in ddd world (at least to my knowledge, i might be completely wrong on that) which i'm trying to understand if i follow - where it ends up. (that's repository vs AR encapsulation question, for example)

Comment: Aggregate encapsulation is indeed a strong statement but was identified from the start as a possible friction point with real tools. If I remember correctly, the original blue book said something like "if the platform/language doesn't allow to lock up everything, you'll have to rely on programmer discipline".

Comment: that makes perfect sense! /i see you are familiar with c#. obviously, `friend` class as defined in c++ would be neat solution. have you found some elegant enough counterpart for `friend` in c#?

Comment: There's no equivalent. You can use `InternalsVisibleTo` but it's for assemblies, not classes.

Answer (score 0):

These questions that you have do not exist in a CQRS architecture, where the Write model (the Aggregate) is different from a Read model. In a flat architecture, the Aggregate must expose read/query methods, otherwise it would be pointless.

> 1. Entity should be private to aggregate

Yes, in this way you are clearly expressing the fact that they are not for external use.

> 2. We need a read only copy Value-Object to expose information from an entity (at least for a repository to be able to read it in order to save to db, for example)

The Repositories are a special case and should not be see in the same way as Application/Presentation code. They could be part of the same package/module, in other words they should be able to access the nested entities.

The entities can be viewed/implemented as object with an immutable ID and a Value object representing its state, something like this (in pseudocode):

```
class SomeNestedEntity
{
    private readonly ID;
    private SomeNestedEntityImmutableState state;

    public getState(){ return state; }
    public someCommandMethod(){ state = state.mutateSomehow(); }
}
```

So you see? You could *safely* return the `state` of the nested entity, as it is immutable. There would be some problem with the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) but this is a decision that you would have to make; if you break it by returning the state you make the code simpler to write for the first time but the coupling increases.

> 3. Methods that we have on entity are duplicated on Aggregate (or, vice versa, methods we have to have on Aggregate that handle entity are duplicated on entity)

Yes, this protect the Aggregate's encapsulation and also permits the Aggregate to protect it's invariants.

Comment: thanks for your answer! First let me just say, all i talk about is write side. Read side is completely different part. /What i am not clear about is how would you prevent calling `SomeNestedEntity.someCommandMethod()` outside aggregate? And if we expand that question to more broad one: why have behavior on entity if it should never ever be accessed from anywhere else than from aggregate? Why not just have it on aggregate and turn entity into simple POCO value object?

Comment: @deezg "how would you prevent calling SomeNestedEntity.someCommandMethod() outside aggregate" - you never return the SomeNestedEntity

Comment: @deezg "why have behavior on entity if it should never ever be accessed from anywhere else than from aggregate" - because you want to releave the Aggregate of such behavior, you want to  keep the Aggregate simple, you want to put the behavior along the data it uses etc; in general, the same reason you make a class (entity) in the first place

Comment: could you please check edit at the end of my question? Is that the setup you are describing?

Comment: @deezg yes, if the `state` is immutable.

Comment: Returning immutable objects still breaks encapsulation. Encapsulation is not only about protecting the class-invariants, it is also about protecting **knowledge**. It is a tool for creating an effective abstraction. Abstraction is in turn a tool for breaking up a complex problem into decoupled and maintainable bits.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam yes, I know, however one should decide for himself when to duplicate **everything** in an Aggregate and when not. The one who say otherwise most probable haven't wrote a single line of code ever but only read.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam how is it even theoretically possible to hide aggregates state (knowledge) and at the same time share it? except if we want to make domain persistence aware and dependant which sounds like even worse option (than exposing state). domain events, json representation, etc...all that is just another form of either sharing state/knowledge or making persistence impact your domain design. feels like some rules are simply mutually exclusive.

Comment: @deezg You are still thinking about data, and how to move *it* around instead of decomposing business functions. :) Ok. So "data" *can* move around of course. The key difference is not to move around naked data. For example an `Account.getLedgerItems()` is not ok, since that data belongs to `Account`. So, *why* would we want that data anyway? To make a balance report. Ok, then just ask the `Account` to make it, since he is responsible for all the data: `Account.createBalanceReport()`. So I "get" the data out, it is just inside another object now, and means something different.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam yes yes, that is clear, of course :). but what about `Account.PutOnHold()` (your ML module detect potential fraudulent account usage and need to block it for audit)? Now you have some internal flag `hold=true` which you need to persist. If you don't expose info/state/knowledge - what options are there? (i am sorry for going back and forth around that one, but it just bothers me so much and can't see any neat way out of it) it almost feels like encapsulation & completely persistence agnostic domain are orthogonal (?!)

Comment: @RobertBräutigam without CQRS one cannot use full encapsulation on the Aggregate without breaking SRP; creating balance reports is not the responsibility of the Aggregate; and we will always have the UI, almost all the data needs to be shown to the user.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam and it will break the OCP as well if we need to modify the Aggregate every time we need to do something with the data

Comment: @deezg Oh, I see. *Completely* persistence agnostic domain *is* orthogonal to encapsulation, you're right. But why would you want a completely persistence agnostic domain? Nobody really does that, do they? Java Enterprise projects routinely have persistence (JPA) related stuff (annotations) all over the domain. Even the "purest" DDD applications have "id" fields everywhere, which are really database ids, nothing to do with the business-domain. This sense of "purity" is misguided. We need to separate *behavior*, not technologies.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu I think CQRS is not a requirement for a proper encapsulation with SRP. I'm working on 2 projects right now where objects don't give out data, are not designed using CQRS, but are still persisted (in one project into elasticsearch, the other to google buckets). But, I think I have a different interpretation of SRP, here take a look at my slides for a recent Conference: https://speakerdeck.com/robertbraeutigam/single-responsibility-principle

Comment: @RobertBräutigam persistence is not a problem from my point if view, I use reflection for this. The "problems" come in the complex applications when the UI and the API needs to display the data. This is why we usually need to expose domain data. We still need some level of encapsulation but the main purpose of an Aggregate is to ensure consistency and to enforce the business rules that are in general of write/command nature.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam (this is my understanding of ddd 'rules' so far) one would want persistence agnostic domain because it should pretty much work in any persistence environment. thats why it should stay intact when changing environment but only infrastructure/app layers should change. i would say it does sound as a reasonable requirement to me until it becomes impossible or way too expensive to actually implement.

Comment: btw, the more i think about it, the less i understand why repositores accept actual entities? why dont entities/ARs expose their state wrapped into flat/poco objects and feed that into repository? that way domain stays persistence agnostic and repository still can map that to whatever DAO structure it needs.

Comment: @deezg there are ways to let the persistence get the state without breaking encapsulation, i.e using reflection

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu yes, i know about reflection but i avoid it on purpose. it feels like a backdoor-ish solution fixing some requirements inconsistencies in domain design phase.

Comment: @deezg I see. In any case, all non-event-sourced architectures *suffer* from this (encapsulation of Aggregates vs. usability of Aggregates for persistence and UI purposes). That's why some (me included) prefer the event sourcing, with all the problems that comes with it.

Comment: @deezg It *is* way too expensive to implement. Let's think about this: You separate all persistence out in the bottom, you separate all UI out at the top, you may have additional layers too. Now how many classes (across the whole application) do you have to look at or modify to make a small change in the bottom layers? How about changing your Aggregate to contain an additional state? In my designs, the answer is usually 1. So what should we optimize for? Changing classes/logic, or making sure our code works with a completely different persistence environment?

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu i have to take your word on it as i havent used event sourcing in my projects yet so cant say. i will just comment that my gut feeling tells me i doubt this thing can be fully solved at all. i have a feeling that something in stating very base rules in ddd is too strict. almost idealisic. but, thats just feeling. i cannot say anything for a fact about it.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam well, all i have read about ddd was full of 'purity', very strong statements, insisting completely on principles & design approaches & goals. i can agree i've might have read wrong things but it is what it is. i know very well what is practical but this time i wanted to give a chance to those 'purity insisting approaches' and see where they get me. and now i see they are practically impossible in a way they are being stated. because whole this discussion is actually about workarounds and not well established professional work which would assume well defined methodologies(...)

Comment: @RobertBräutigam (continuation) i dont want to sound anti-ddd in any way; on a contrary, there are some very valuable points in it (crafting software) but i sure did expect its much more defined in a sense of actual methodologies and much less rely on programmers discrete decisions / workarounds & compromises. /e.g. as a programmer familiar with real world problems i absolutely understand your `AR.getJSON()` idea for save but if we allow that than huge part of ddd writings/talk is pure jabber and whishful thinking.

Comment: @deezg you could take away from the DDD only the Bounded contexts and the Ubiquitous language and leave the other

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu could you please elaborate a bit more on that? how do you mean take away?

Comment: @deezg If you do not do full DDD ( with Aggregates, value objects and so on), you could make use only of Bounded contexts and Ubiquitous language in your software development.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu yes yes, of course. but i do want use things like aggregates as they really do make sense and add huge value to software development as profession and crafting process. its just that feeling that some aspects of fitting all those pieces together are not formulated good enough yet. i will post a new question about one such piece: why repository should accept AR instead of some data model (exposed by domain)? (question actually boils down to your solution with exposing immutable VOs)

Answer (score 0):

I won't write too much. Just an example. A car and a gear. The car is the aggregate root. The gear is a child entity